# Java - Add user input to 3 arrays? (Parallel Arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, input

So I have 3 Parallel Arrays. I need a method that will allow for the user to add to these arrays. As well as another method to be able to identify a certain item and remove it. As well as another method to identify an item and edit/change the contents of that item in the array.

These are my 3 arrays...

I need to add the brand name of the computer to: 
String[] computerBrand

I need to add the processor speeds to:
double[] computerSpeed

and I need to add the computers price to: 
double[] computerPrice

The first array (string) holds the brand name of computer. (Dell)
the second array (double) holds the processor speed of the computer. (2.5)
the third array (double) holds the price of the computer. (1500)

How do I take user input and put them in the array?

(I CANNOT USE ARRAYLISTS)

Comment: Why are you using parallel arrays? This is exactly the situation where you should have an array of class `Computer`.

Comment: This question is about object phobia and not parallel arrays.

Comment: Professor requires us to use parallel arrays for some odd reason on this project O.o

Comment: Lol why? Classes here is so useful and more intuitive than 3 arrays. Anyway it's the same as use one array with the difference you will use 3 arrays using the same index.

Comment: Don't ask me. Maybe because my professor learned to code 30 years ago? lol who knows. But it specifically says in the instructions: 
"DONT USE ARRAYLISTS! USE PARALLEL ARRAYS!" And I can't find help anywhere online cuz no one uses parallel arrays!

Comment: When you code in C, you use structs and create arrays of structs, IIRC

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, good point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For taking input look at the Scanner class.

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

For adding the values to your arrays just do this:

`computerBrand[i] = <value_brand>;`
`computerSpeed[i] = <value_speed>;`
`computerPrice[i] = <value_price>;`
`i++;`

where these 3 values are the one read by the Scanner,
and `i` is some index/counter integer variable.

But first make sure you initialize your arrays e.g.:

```
computerBrand = new String[100];
computerSpeed = new double[100];
computerPrice = new double[100];
```

Comment: Okay so I got it to add to the arrays, but it's adding to the beginning of the array. Is there any easy way to make it add to the end of the arrays, as well as when I exit my program it is supposed to save the arrays back to the computers.txt file neatly. But for some reason it is screwing up the format of the lines and stuff in my .txt file after saving and exiting.

Comment: My pseudo-code is adding to the ends of the arrays. The 3 arrays share a common index/counter variable, that's all.

Comment: This is how my computers.txt looks before adding to it then saving+exiting: http://hastebin.com/wajaholero.md      but then after it looks like this: http://hastebin.com/qerubemumi

Comment: Ahhh that is due to my File Output/Saving and Exiting issues. Let me try and fix it.

Comment: WHere do I declare i or counter variable? In the main? But then I don't understand how it knows where the end of my arrays are. Like where the last string or double is or last line or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the arrays
// (anyway It's better to use double for price and speed)
String[] computerBrand = new String[5];
String[] computerSpeed = new String[5];
String[] computerPrice = new String[5];

//
// Now you have 3 arrays which contains computer info

// A Computer with index 0 will contains his name in computerBrand[0], speed in computerSpeed[0] and price in computerPrice[0]

// Put info into the arrays, here is random in the real code you get the info from the user.. you can understand it's the same way you use for standard arrays (it's anyway arrays)
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    computerBrand[i] = "Computer " + i;
    computerSpeed[i] = String.valueOf(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
    computerPrice[i] = String.valueOf(Math.floor(Math.random()*500));
}

// print info
//
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    // As you can see, i have used the same index in every array
    System.out.println(
            "Brand: " + computerBrand[i] +
            " Speed: " + computerSpeed[i] +
            " Price: " + computerPrice[i] + "E"
    );
}
```

By reading the code you can understand a simple thing: every array will share the same index.

For your real code, you just need to get name, price and speed of the pc and put everything in the arrays using the same index. If you use it in separate code you can store the last index and use it (more info depends on how it should work.).