# Java - Make my unfilled arrays not print out null and 0?

Tags: java, arrays, input, parallel-processing, output

So I have to use 3 parallel arrays. (NO ARRAY LISTS)

```
    String fileName = "computers.txt"; //file that lists computers       
    String[] computerBrand = new String[15]; //computer brand array      
    double[] computerSpeed = new double[15]; //computers processor speed array       
    double[] computerPrice = new double[15]; //computers price array
```

I am giving the user the ability to add computers to the arrays, edit computers, and remove computers from the arrays. Then at the end of the program when they decide to exit, it saves the arrays back to computers.txt and closes.

My issues:

1.) My arrays are set to size 15, but there are only 10 computers in the computers.txt(giving space for more computers to be added) So when I print out the arrays to the console, it prints out the computer brands, speeds, and prices but it also prints out null, null, null, for the last 5 brands, and zeros for the last 5 speeds & prices. How can I fix this?

2.) With using Parallel Arrays (no arraylists) how can I make sure that if the user adds like 6 or 7 computers to the list, the arrays can expand with it? Some info on instructions: "Because the number of items in the arrays may change throughout program execution, you will need to keep an additional integer variable with the number of items in your arrays."

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do the indices of the arrays match for one computer? Shouldn't you have a `Computer` class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Loop and print them yourself. Print all elements from index 0 to index `N-1`,
where `N` is the last/current value of `i`. Here `i` is ... See my previous answer here:
[Java - Add user input to 3 arrays? (Parallel Arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504798/2300597)

2) Before you try adding a new element first check if `i == computerBrand.length`
is true. If so you need to extend your 3 arrays. So recreate the 3 arrays but increase
their sizes by say 10.

`String[] computerBrandExtended = new String[computerBrand.length + 10];`
`loop and copy all values from computerBrand to computerBrandExtended;`
`computerBrand = computerBrandExtended;`

Do this for all 3 arrays. Now you have some room again.

Answer (score 0):

Create ArrayList it will suits to your problem

This is the javadoc for arrayList

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
```

they have worked on dynamic memory allocation, its very easy to work with them like adding deletion

Comment: OP stated that they either don't want to or can't use ArrayLists in their solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create something like this:

```
class Computer {
    String brabd;
    double price;
    double speed;
}
```

and then use Collection of computers:

```
List<Computer> computers = new ArrayList<>();
```